# How can I use BLS12-381 curve operations:EIP-2537, Whether it's on a public or private chain

Tags: verify, code, pairings, curve

Recently I have been doing an experiment to sign smart contracts with bls12-381, but I can't find any tutorial or code for this, Is there any way to do that? please tell me  if you know about it.

Answer (score 2):

While EIP-2537 *(featuring **BLS12-381**)* has not been approved nor finalized yet, you can run a private network supporting that precompile.

---

In addition to that, there's a nice GitHub ***Solidity*** library *(although this library is originally intended to test the Celo proposals, but the code shouldn't differ on Ethereum)* that brings some examples of using ***BLS12-381*** operations in Solidity smart contracts *(which is a wrapper around **EIP-2537**)*.

- https://github.com/prestwich/b12-sol/blob/main/contracts/B12.sol

It does though warn you too that:

> **These EIPs are not active on mainnet at time of writing, and require specialized client software to execute.**